# Django ImportError: cannot import name apps

Tags: django, import, localhost, python-import, importerror

This error: 
`ImportError: cannot import name apps`

occurs whenever I try to run any django app on a localserver. After some research, a possible reason may be due to recursive importing but this should not be the case when I try running my other projects.

What could be possible reasons for this and how could I solve it?

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as the probably offending imports?

Comment: Not sure if related but make sure all the apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS` do exist in your project folder. Next check your imports, such as `Models` and `Forms`. Also check for typos.

Comment: which version of Django do you use for your project?  It can occur if your project is on an old version of Django (< 1.7) but you use a 3rd party app which expects Django 1.7 or above and contains code which tries to `from django import apps`.  but this should be obvious if you read the stacktrace